# 502 error when trying to authorize Gitlab CI as an Application in Gitlab

Tags: nginx, oauth, gitlab, unicorn, gitlab-ci

So I have a Gitlab and a Gitlab-CI server running on separate machines. I am trying to authorize CI as an application via OAuth, but when I hit the Authorize button, I get a 502 error. I've confirmed that I'm using the correct app ID and secret for the application I've created for the CI server in Gitlab, and unfortunately, the nginx and unicorn logs for gitlab aren't exactly providing me with much useful information. Has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before?

Comment: I should note that this is what the nginx logs on the CI server are saying:  
`2015/08/07 15:13:15 [error] 4921#0: *3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.14.1, server: amsterdam.sdelements.com, request: "GET /user_sessions/callback HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/sockets/gitlab.socket:/user_sessions/callback", host: "amsterdam.sdelements.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your gitlab server certification into gitlab-ci server?

Best.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you elaborate a little on what you mean?

Comment: 1. append your cert bundle to the end of the /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs.pem file

2. add a custom NGiNX config to gitlab.rb so nginx['gitlab_nginx_custom_config'] = "verify_depth 2" is set 

3. set custom rails env vars for your ssl cert file locations (will edit comment in a bit with the code for this) 

4. copy or symlink your trusted certs into /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs